# only show load more button if there is something to load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, hide

I added a load more button with the plugin "easy load more" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/). The button is working great except that it will still show up even if there are no more posts to display. I would like to hide the button if there are no more posts left to load. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could do this?  I've been stumped on this for weeks, I would really appreciate any help!

frontend.js

```html
;(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.elm-button').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var $that = $(this),
url = $that.attr('data-href'),
nextPage = parseInt($that.attr('data-page'), 10) + 1,
maxPages = parseInt($that.attr('data-max-pages'), 10);

$that.addClass('is-loading');

if (url.indexOf('?') > 0) {
url += '&';
} else {
url += '?';
}

url += 'paged=' + nextPage;

$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : url,
dataType: 'text'
}).done(function (data) {

$that.removeClass('is-loading');

if ($(elm_button_vars.wrapper).length) {
$(elm_button_vars.wrapper).append($($.parseHTML(data)).find(elm_button_vars.wrapper).addBack(elm_button_vars.wrapper).html());
} else {
console.log('Please update Easy Load More settings with post list wrapper selector.');
}

if ( nextPage == maxPages ) {
$that.remove();
} else {
$that.attr('data-page', nextPage);
}

}).fail(function () {
console.log('Ajax failed. Navigating to ' + url + '.');
window.location.href = url;
});

return false;
});
});

}(jQuery));
```

and my front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <div class="large-front-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                </div>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <div class="front-thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></div>
                <a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that plugin, but on the `AJAX Load More Plugin` it adds a class of `done` to the load more button when there are no more posts, so you can hide it with javascript targeting that class. Does this plugin do something similar?

Comment: How would I find this out?

Comment: load all of the posts using the button on the page. When you get to the end, is a class added to the button? check with `developer tools`

Comment: No there is no class added to the button at the end.  One thing I should mention is that the button will disappear at the end if you press it again. (but like I said I want it to not show up at all if there are no posts to load) However when checking the button in developer tools (the second page of button) it said <button class="elm-button" data-href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/" data-page="2" data-max-pages="3"> - so it seems that the button is disappearing at the max # of pages + 1 extra page.
(right now I have enough posts that it should exactly fill 2 pages)

Comment: So you could use jquery to target that data attribute

Maybe something like 

`if(+$('.elm-button').data('max-pages') - +$('.elm-button').data('page') == 1){$('.elm-button').css('display','none');}`

Comment: Not exactly sure if that's the right logic, but something like that should work. Might be if if == 0. Not sure

Comment: Where should I place this? Just at the end of fronted.js?

Comment: I think right above the line that says `}).fail(function () {`

Comment: I really appreciate the help. However, the load more button will disappear but only at the end of the second page, but if there are any more posts the button will still show up.  There are 14 posts on a page before the load more button appears.  So if there was 28 posts the button will disappear. But if there were say 33 or 42 posts the load more button will still appear even if no posts are left to load.